# cannot find function `serialize` in module `jwt_numeric_date`

Tags: rust

when I compile the new rust mod `jwt_numeric_date`(`cargo 1.54.0 (5ae8d74b3 2021-06-22)`), shows error:

```
    error[E0425]: cannot find function `serialize` in module `jwt_numeric_date`
 --> src/jwt_util.rs:6:28
  |
6 | #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `jwt_numeric_date`
  |
  = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Serialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider importing this function
  |
2 | use rocket::figment::util::vec_tuple_map::serialize;
```

the rust code look like this:

```
use chrono::{Duration, TimeZone, Utc, DateTime, Timelike};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Claims {
    sub: String,
    #[serde(with = "jwt_numeric_date")]
    iat: DateTime<Utc>,
    #[serde(with = "jwt_numeric_date")]
    exp: DateTime<Utc>,
}

impl Claims {
    pub fn new(sub: String, iat: DateTime<Utc>, exp: DateTime<Utc>) -> Self {
        let iat = iat.date().and_hms_milli(iat.hour(), iat.minute(), iat.second(), 0);
        let exp = exp.date().and_hms_milli(exp.hour(), exp.minute(), exp.second(), 0);
        Self { sub, iat, exp }
    }
}
pub mod jwt_numeric_date {

    use serde::{self, Deserialize, Deserializer, Serializer,Serialize};

    pub fn parse_jwt(token: &str) {

    }
}
```

I have import the `Serialize` in mod `jwt_numeric_date`, why still tell this error. I have check this [issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1629) and make sure my cargo import enable derive feature like this:

```
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
```

Comment: and `jwt_numeric_date` is ? I starting to be annoying by your 4 questions on jwt where I take take to read and you delete after

Comment: There is an exact same example given here: https://serde.rs/custom-date-format.html Please try that

Comment: Thank you, I will read the docs and recheck my code.@GurwinderSingh

Comment: See the documentation for [`#[serde(with = ...)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#with), the `jwt_numeric_date` module is expected to have `serialize` and `deserialize` *functions* defined, not `Serialize` and `Deserialize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement the `serialize` and `deserialize` in the mod jwt_numeric_date like this:

```
/// Serializes a DateTime<Utc> to a Unix timestamp (milliseconds since 1970/1/1T00:00:00T)
    pub fn serialize<S>(date: &DateTime<Utc>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where
            S: Serializer,
    {
        let timestamp = date.timestamp();
        serializer.serialize_i64(timestamp)
    }

    /// Attempts to deserialize an i64 and use as a Unix timestamp
    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<DateTime<Utc>, D::Error>
        where
            D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        Utc.timestamp_opt(i64::deserialize(deserializer)?, 0)
            .single() // If there are multiple or no valid DateTimes from timestamp, return None
            .ok_or_else(|| serde::de::Error::custom("invalid Unix timestamp value"))
    }
```